# Desirable jungle route for Shaco after patch 4.20?

Tags: league-of-legends

I play Shaco a 3rd of my most played champs and jungling with him with ASPD runes is a no problem at all.

However, after the latest patch (where jungle items are so cool) my jungle routine kinda messed up.

Before, I could go blue > wraith > red > gank.

But now, even with blue then wolves, my HP struggles and so my damage.

Any ideas for jungle routes?

Answer (score 2):

This is a cool route which definitly needs some practice.

Comment: With aspd runes in quints, the hp result in the vid is not much different to what I obtained, not to mention I used 27/0/3.

Answer (score 0):

Standard:

1. Bot side small camp (Smite)
2. Bot side buff (Blue Side - Red Buff, Purple side - Blue Buff)
3. Other Buff
4. Crab

Invade

1. Top side main buff
2. Hide in enemy's top side buff with boxes setup
3. Kill enemy and take his/her buff
4. Run away